SwiftUI Picker does not change the value
Following example has a very simple class with couple properties of string and enum types.
But somehow Picker does not change value.
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?
import SwiftUI

enum AccountType: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: AccountType { self }
    
    case Bank = "Bank Account"
    case Cash = "Cash in a wallet"
}

class Account {
    var name: String = ""
    var type: AccountType = .Cash
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var newAccount: Account = Account()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Type", selection: $newAccount.type) {
                ForEach(AccountType.allCases) { (type: AccountType) in
                    Text(type.rawValue).tag(type)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


The selection property and the items in the picker must be of the same type so change the selection property to be of type AccountType

Aren't they of the same type?
            ForEach(AccountType.allCases) { (type: AccountType) in
                Text(type.rawValue).tag(type)
            }


The selection property, newAccount.

Ah! Gotcha. is there any way a selection property can be a property of an object?

Why is the id of type self?

Why is Account a class? Changing this to a struct or a @Observable class would fix this.

You can change your code like this
class Account: ObservableObject {
    var name: String = ""
    @Published var type: AccountType = .Cash
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var newAccount: Account = Account()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Type", selection: $newAccount.type) {
                ForEach(AccountType.allCases) { (type: AccountType) in
                    Text(type.rawValue).tag(type)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Only the Published changes update the UI. You will have to mark type variable as @Published and mark the object of Account with @StateObject instead of @State.
